# RegEx in FileZilla for Sub Folders

Tags: regex, filezilla

I have a RegEx of `\/lib\/dam\/\d+\/0`

Using FileZilla, I only want to display folders that have paths that end in 0 e.g.

```
/lib/dam/1000/0
/lib/dam/2000/0
/lib/dam/3000/0
...
/lib/dam/200000/0
```

However the RegEx I have doesn't work in FileZilla but does on https://regex101.com. Please advise!

Comment: Try: A) replacing `\d` with `[0-9]` and/or B) anchoring your search with `^`/`$`.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean anchoring? Option (A) doesn't work by itself

Comment: Might as well read up on [regex anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), whether or not it helps :)

Comment: Still no go I'm afraid! Works in all the online testers

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: maybe the use of `+` is a problem, since it is not mentioned here: https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Regular_Expressions try `\d\d*` instead of `\d+`